# Show recent API-made comments for 10k users/mods to review

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, api

Since chances are good that even with the limitations some people will abuse the [new write API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) it would probably be a good idea to show all comments made by it on a page within the 10k tools or mod tools.

The best order for entries to be displayed would probably be a combination of how new the app is and the amount of comments made by the app which were flagged+deleted.

Comment: Heck, introduce a new moderation dashboard for all activities performed via the API.